# Unpack two variables into two columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function called ReturnDateRange which will return two dates.
I am trying to apply this function on a column called 'zRow' in a dataFrame, and store the result in two different columns.

The below will store both results, as a tuple in one column:

```
df['t1']= df['zRow'].map(ReturnDateRange)
```

The following returns a ValueError: Too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
df['t1'], df['t2']= df['zRow'].map(ReturnDateRange)
```

But the function always returns two dates, or a single None.

UPDATE: I tried returning two zeros instead of None. Still get the same error.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does `df['t1'], df['t2']= pd.Series(df['zRow'].map(ReturnDateRange))` work?

Comment: I get the same ValueError (too many values to unpack)

Comment: I expected @EdChum 's suggestion to work.  I suggest you provide more information.  Use this post as a guide for what information to provide.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try df['t1']= df['zRow'].map(ReturnDateRange[0])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Too many values to unpack" error is because its unpacking the rows, rather than columns. Thus a *transpose* will help, but I feel like there's a nicer way to fix this.

In the mean time, this works, if not very elegantly...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(5,2)),columns=["a","b"])

def mapper(x):
    return ('first', 'second')

data['t1'], data['t2'] = data['b'].map(mapper).apply(pd.Series).values.T

print data
```

Giving this result:

```
     a    b     t1      t2
0  0.0  0.0  first  second
1  0.0  0.0  first  second
2  0.0  0.0  first  second
3  0.0  0.0  first  second
4  0.0  0.0  first  second
```

This might help someone else pin-down a better solution at least.

Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550414/how-to-split-column-of-tuples-in-pandas-dataframe) post here too.

**Edit**, found a nicer way to fix it. Use:

```
data[['t1', 't2']] = data['b'].map(mapper).apply(pd.Series)
```

So, in your case, this should work:

```
df[['t1', 't2']] = df['zRow'].map(ReturnDateRange).apply(pd.Series)
```