# Apply a function to column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe with user comments on a movie and would like to parse examples of when a user describes a movie as "movie1" meets "movie2"

```
User id     Old id_New id   Score   Comments
947952018   3101_771355141  3.0 If you want to see a comedy and have a stupid ...
805407067   11903_18330     5.0 Argento?s fever dream masterpiece. Fairy tale ...
901306244   16077_771225176 4.5 Evil Dead II meets Brothers Grimm and Hawkeye ...
901306244   NaN_381422014   1.0 Biggest disappointment! There&#39;s a host of ...
15169683    NaN_22471       3.0 You know in the original story of Pinocchio he...
```

I've written a function that takes in a comment, finds the word "meets" and takes the first n words before and after meets and returns (hopefully) the essence of the titles of movie1 & movie2, which I plan to fuzzy match later to titles in another dataframe.

```
def parse_movie(comment, num_words):
    words = comment.partition('meets')
    words_before = words[0].split(maxsplit=num_words)[-num_words:] 
    words_after = words[2].split(maxsplit=num_words)[:num_words]
    movie1 = ' '.join(words_before)
    movie2 = ' '.join(words_after)
    return movie1, movie2
```

How can I apply this function on the comments column of the original pandas dataframe and put the returned movie1 and movie2 titles in separate columns?  I tried

```
df['Comments'].apply(parse_titles)
```

but then I cannot specify num_words I'd like to use.  Operating directly on the column also doesn't work for me, and I'm not sure how to put the new movies into new columns.

```
parse_movie(sample['Comments'], 4)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'partition'
```

Suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You can pass arguments with `apply()` using the `args` argument.  Have a look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [how to split column of tuples in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29550458/5932828) answer. This can be done using lambda function and apply(pd.Series). Save the results into dataframe column 'movie1' and 'movie2'.

```
num_words = 4
df[['movie1','movie2']] = df['comments'].apply(lambda comment: parse_movie(comment, num_words)).apply(pd.Series)
```