# Split up Pandas column by regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
names = ["(alpha, bravo, charlie, delta)", "(echo, foxtrot, golf, hotel)"]
vals = [2, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(names, vals)), columns=["name", "val"])
df


                             name  val
0  (alpha, bravo, charlie, delta)    2
1    (echo, foxtrot, golf, hotel)    4
```

I want to make a new dataframe like

```
   first   second    third fourth  val
0  alpha    bravo  charlie  delta     2
1   echo  foxtrot     golf  hotel     4
```

All I know about the name column is that it's comma separated and enclosed in parenthesis, and that it's 4 items long.
I get that this has to use regex, which is totally fine, but I don't know how to get multiple groups out of the same pandas column at the same time.

I imagine that this pattern would work, but I don't know how to implement it with pandas.

```
\(([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)\)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550414/how-to-split-column-of-tuples-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Use pd.DataFrame(col.tolist()) on that particular column

Comment: min2bro's pd.DataFrame(col.tolist()) is definitely the way to go on this.