# Search the nearest value in an excel list python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, gps

I have a GPS tracker plugged in my USB-port, now this GPS tracker gives me my current location in coordinates like this `(53.545, 9.658)`. Now I also have an excel file which contains hundred of similar coordinates. I want my code to search in that Excel file for the values that are nearest to my GPS coordinates `(53.545, 9.658)` and simply print that row for me.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_excel("my_coordinates")

def closest(df, v): 
      
    return df[min(range(len(df)), key = lambda i: abs(df[i]-v))] 
    v = (53.545, 9.658)

print(df, v)
```

Comment: see : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222315/geopandas-find-nearest-point-in-other-dataframe

Comment: Split df to columns https://stackoverflow.com/q/29550414/6692898 Then calc distance with https://stackoverflow.com/a/19412565/6692898 using full columns as args, avoid itertuples