# Pandas Dataframe column list of tuples to simple column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[(1,2), (3,4)], [(5,6), (7,8), (9,10)]]})
```

I would like to transform into this format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5,7,9], 'b':[2,4,6,8,10]})
```

So basically have all the tuples[0] into column A and the tuples[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550414/how-to-split-column-of-tuples-in-pandas-dataframe) into column B

I found this Stack Overflow question helpful : [how to split column of tuples in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550414/how-to-split-column-of-tuples-in-pandas-dataframe) but I have a list of tuples and not a single tuple in the columns.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with convert tuples to lists and then pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].explode().tolist(), columns=['A','B'])
print (df)
   A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
3  7   8
4  9  10
```

Or use list comprehension with flatten nested lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in df['A'] for y in x], columns=['A','B'])
print (df)
   A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
3  7   8
4  9  10
```

EDIT: If add new empty list both solutions working different:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[(1,2), (3,4)], [(5,6), (7,8), (9,10)], []]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].explode().tolist(), columns=['A','B'])
print (df1)
     A     B
0  1.0   2.0
1  3.0   4.0
2  5.0   6.0
3  7.0   8.0
4  9.0  10.0
5  NaN   NaN

df1 = pd.DataFrame([y for x in df['A'] for y in x], columns=['A','B'])
print (df1)
   A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
3  7   8
4  9  10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(df["A"]), columns=["A", "B"])
# df

   A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
3  7   8
4  9  10
```