# to_list not working with pandas when null values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples, tolist

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[None,1, 2], 'b':[None, (1,2), (3,4)]}) 


    a   b
0   NaN None
1   1.0 (1, 2)
2   2.0 (3, 4)
```

I want to set the tuple in the column be to each have their own column. However, I have an issue with my approach

```
df[['b1', 'b2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['b'].tolist(), index=df.index)

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I tried to fillna will an empty tuple, but it won't take a tuple. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can first [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) the `NaN` values in column `b` then create a new dataframe from the remaining elements in column `b` and assign the resulting dataframe to the columns `b1` and `b2`:

```
b = df['b'].dropna()
df[['b1', 'b2']] = pd.DataFrame(b.tolist(), index=b.index)
```

---

```
>>> df

     a       b   b1   b2
0  NaN    None  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  (1, 2)  1.0  2.0
2  2.0  (3, 4)  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: This answer has just saved by hours of effort trying to find a work-around for an error in a function that I had written previously. For me, NaN values in the middle rows did not cause a problem, it was only a NaN value in the first position that caused an issue.

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise, [this solution by piR²](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56081799/8881141) works in your case as well:

```
df["x"], df["y"] = df.b.str
```

Output:

```
     a       b    x    y
0  NaN    None  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  (1, 2)  1.0  2.0
2  2.0  (3, 4)  3.0  4.0
```

Having said this - there is a FutureWarning `Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases.`, so this is not a long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

Transform None to (None, None) as follows before creating the 2 columns:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].map(lambda x: (None, None) if x is None else x)
```

Then you can get the desired result with your step:

```
    df[['b1', 'b2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['b'].tolist(), index=df.index)
    print(df)

Output:
    a              b     b1  b2
0   NaN (None, None)    NaN NaN
1   1.0       (1, 2)    1.0 2.0
2   2.0       (3, 4)    3.0 4.0
```

If you want the None in column b untouched, you can use:

```
    df[['b1', 'b2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['b'].map(lambda x: (None, None) if x is None else x).tolist(), index=df.index)

    print(df)

Output:
    a         b    b1  b2
0   NaN    None   NaN NaN
1   1.0  (1, 2)   1.0 2.0
2   2.0  (3, 4)   3.0 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generalized solution if you have tuples with different number of elements would be to create a custom function like the following

```
def create_columns_from_tuple(df, tuple_col):
    
    # get max length of tuples
    max_len = df[tuple_col].apply(lambda x: 0 if x is None else len(x)).max()
    
    # select rows with non-empty tuples
    df_full = df.loc[df[tuple_col].notna()]
    
    # create dataframe with exploded tuples
    df_full_exploded = pd.DataFrame(df_full[tuple_col].tolist(),
                                    index=df_full.index, 
                                    columns=[tuple_col + str(n) for n in range(1, max_len+1)])
    
    # merge the two dataframes by index
    result = df.merge(df_full_exploded, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
    
    return result
```

In this function you pass your dataframe and the name of the tuple column. The function will automatically create as many columns as the maximum length of your tuples.

```
create_columns_from_tuple(df, tuple_col='b')
#      a       b   b1   b2
# 0  NaN    None  NaN  NaN
# 1  1.0  (1, 2)  1.0  2.0
# 2  2.0  (3, 4)  3.0  4.0
```

---

If you have tuples with different number of elements:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[None,1, 2], 'b':[None, (1,2,42), (3,4)]}) 
create_columns_from_tuple(df, tuple_col='b')
#      a           b   b1   b2    b3
# 0  NaN        None  NaN  NaN   NaN
# 1  1.0  (1, 2, 42)  1.0  2.0  42.0
# 2  2.0      (3, 4)  3.0  4.0   NaN
```