# Splitting tuples in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe `df` containing tuples like below in Column A

```
|  ID      |  A         |
+----------+------------+
|0         |(1, [a])    |
|1         |(2, [a,b])  |
|2         |(3, [c,a,b])|
+----------+------------+
```

I want to split the tuples in the above df and want to see my new dataframe `df` like below.

```
|  ID      |  A         |    B     |
+----------+------------+----------+
|0         | 1          |  [a]     |
|1         | 2          |  [a,b]   |
|2         | 3          |  [c,a,b] |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

So, how can I split the tuple in the above dataframe `df`?

Comment: Many solutions, same like answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55458565/2901002)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor, make sure to start with creating B to avoid losing the data in A:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str[1]
df['A'] = df['A'].str[0]
```

alternative:

```
df[['A', 'B']] = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].to_list(), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

output:

```
   ID  A          B
0   0  1        [a]
1   1  2     [a, b]
2   2  3  [c, a, b]
```