# pandas - running into problems setting multiple columns using results from pd.apply()

Tags: pandas

I have a function that returns tuples. When I apply this to my pandas dataframe using pd.apply() function, the results look this way.

[image]

The Date here is an index and I am not interested in it.
I want to create two new columns in a dataframe and set their values to the values you see in these tuples.

How do I do this?
I tried the following:

[image]

This errors out citing mismatch between expected and available values. It is seeing these tuples as a single entity, so those two columns I specified on the left hand side are a problem. Its expecting only one.

And what I need is to break it down into two parts that can be used to set two different columns.

Whats the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split a column of tuples in a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550414/how-can-i-split-a-column-of-tuples-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your function return a `pd.Series`, this will be expanded into a frame.

```
orders.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(myFunc(x)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

use zip

```
orders['a'], orders['b'] = zip(*df['your_column'])
```